# Borrow Checker Not Releasing Immutable Borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm having a problem in the code below where the borrow checker complains about an immutable borrow in the call to `self.entries.push()` despite placing all the temporary code inside its own scope.

I have checked other posts with similar problems, but I can't figure out how to adapt the code to my own situation -- I'm still pretty new to Rust. Suggestions?

```rust
impl Entry {
    pub fn chain(&self, spair: &SigningPair, expires: u16)
    -> Result<(Entry, HashMap<&str,CryptoString>), MensagoError> {
        // New Entry and HashMap allocated in here to be returned
    }
}

pub struct Keycard {
    _type: EntryType,
    pub entries: Vec<Entry>,
}

impl Keycard {
    pub fn get_current(&self) -> Option<&Entry> {
        // ...
    }

    pub fn chain(&mut self, spair: &SigningPair, expires: u16)
    -> Result<HashMap<&str,CryptoString>, MensagoError> {
        let (newentry, keys) =  {
            let entry = match self.get_current() {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => { return Err(MensagoError::ErrEmptyData) }
            };
            
            match entry.get_field("Type")?.as_str() {
                "Organization" | "User" => (),
                _ => { return Err(MensagoError::ErrInvalidKeycard) }
            } 
            
            entry.chain(spair, expires)?
        };

        self.entries.push(newentry);
        
        Ok(keys)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the lifetime of the key of your hash map?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question sadly lacks reproducibility. At least the exact error message is definitely needed, but stackoverflow policy demands that you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and we would appreciate that as well). Your current example contains a *lot* of undefined types.

Comment: Is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=40058fe33f2b38a56fdfd4a4b4650318) a minimal reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, not runnable -- there is a lot of backend code this sits on top of. I never even imagined that someone would actually try to run this, so thank you both for pointing this out -- will note for future SO interaction. I just tried to provide the minimum code to convey the problem. If it helps, you could check out the code with the error in place at https://gitlab.com/mensago/libkeycard.git where the problem is in keycard.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the error is because the returnvalue of `chain()` is incorrect:

- `HashMap<&str,CryptoString>` should be `HashMap<&'static str,CryptoString>` or `HashMap<String,CryptoString>`

The explanation is a little bit longer, though.

Rust borrow checker demands that a value can be:

- borrowed **immutably** by **many** borrowers or
- borrowed **mutably** by **exactly one** borrower
- no other borrows can exist (mutable or immutable) when a value gets modified

You try to modify the value `self.entry` at `self.entries.push(newentry)`. Therefore, there must not be any borrows that reference `self.entry`.

Sadly, a borrow chain exists that borrows `self`, which indirectly also borrows `self.entry` at that point in time:

- the type of `newentry` contains a reference, `&str`. `newentry` got created in `.chain()`, where `&str` has no lifetime annotations and therefore has the same lifetime as `entry`.
- `entry` is created by `self.get_current()`, where again, `&Entry` is a reference with no explicit lifetime annotation and therefore has the same lifetime as `self`.

Which means through the chain `newentry` -> `entry` -> `self`, the `self` object is still borrowed while you try to call `self.entries.push()`. This is exactly what the error message is trying to tell you.

There are several solutions to those problems usually:

- Introduce `Rc` instead of references
- `.clone()` somewhere in between to break the reference chain
- make sure that the reference chain actually makes sense in the first place, and if not, introduce lifetimes appropriately

In your case I think it's solution #3, as there is no reason why `newentry` should borrow `entry`. The type `&str` is most likely incorrect and should be `&'static str`. In my experience, using `&str` as a key for `HashMap` doesn't make much sense, it should be either `&'static str` (= global constant string like `"hello"`) or the owned, mutable version `String`. Using a temporary reference as a key is quite strange and therefore most likely a beginner error.

The fixed version is:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Entry;
pub struct SigningPair;
pub struct CryptoString;
pub enum MensagoError {
    ErrEmptyData,
    ErrInvalidKeycard,
}
pub struct EntryType;

impl Entry {
    pub fn chain(
        &self,
        _: &SigningPair,
        _: u16,
    ) -> Result<(Entry, HashMap<&'static str, CryptoString>), MensagoError> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn get_field(&self, _: &str) -> Result<String, MensagoError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct Keycard {
    _type: EntryType,
    pub entries: Vec<Entry>,
}

impl Keycard {
    pub fn get_current(&self) -> Option<&Entry> {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn chain(
        &mut self,
        spair: &SigningPair,
        expires: u16,
    ) -> Result<HashMap<&str, CryptoString>, MensagoError> {
        let (newentry, keys) = {
            let entry = match self.get_current() {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => return Err(MensagoError::ErrEmptyData),
            };

            match entry.get_field("Type")?.as_str() {
                "Organization" | "User" => (),
                _ => return Err(MensagoError::ErrInvalidKeycard),
            }

            entry.chain(spair, expires)?
        };

        self.entries.push(newentry);

        Ok(keys)
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as the key to the hashmap isn't borrowed from `&'a self` you can get away with `&'b str` for the key (but it's unclear who would own the str with a longer lifetime than 'a with the limited code available, so your more general answer is sufficient)

Comment: `'a` got created at `self.get_current()`, so no matter what, `'b` should outlive it and break the chain (as `'b'` definitely already existed when the `HashMap` got created). So yes, what you say is correct. But I don't think throwing explicit lifetimes at Rust beginners is a good idea :D let's keep this discussion in the comment section here though, as reference.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so thoroughly. The output from `entry.chain` aren't references but totally new objects allocated -- the HashMap is allocated with `new()` and the Entry object is cloned from `entry`. Shouldn't `entry` be dropped at the end of the scope block that it was assigned in?

Comment: @DarkWyrm They *are* references. They contain `&str`, which is a reference. And without a lifetime annotation in `chain()`, it assumes that the `&str` reference is borrowed from `self`, which in this case is `entry`. Dropping `entry` doesn't solve the problem, because the entire reference chain is only 'finished' when every direct or indirect reference that is connected to it is dropped.

Comment: @DarkWyrm  Rather the opposite ... you are not *allowed* to drop `entry`, because that would potentially leave `&str` in `newentry` dangling. So the fact alone that `entry` is dropped will cause an error. See this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8005b12b87049bb3599a22e2267c424c

Comment: I understand now. Thank you! I ended up adding moving &str -> &static str in the relevant places and it works now as intended.

Comment: Note that this is a programming error in all languages, in most other languages it's just undefined behaviour but still compiles. Like in C++; you can most certainly create a reference in C++ and then destroy the original object while still holding the reference. The resulting behaviour could be anything, but most likely it would work sometimes with weird crashes that are hard to debug. But theoretically something like this could even be an entry point for a hacker to take over your system. Rust by definition has no undefined behaviour, so the compiler doesn't allow this.